# How to get child_object in python-ldap

Tags: python, ldap

I'm totally new in using LDAP with python, am trying to perform a query on the LDAP tree that is shown in the image.

[image: LDAP Tree]

Using the package `python-ldap` . as you see, the tree is like this :

ou=Organization >> ou=Company >> ou=Brasil >>
Then after the country, there are many cities, I managed to reach this city .. but there are some other cities that have some kind of (Sub-Cities) under it as you see in ou=Sao Paulo, it has 3 sub-cities after it.

What I need to do is :

1- Get to the child cities after the main cities.
2- get to be able to loop over every CN=Gateway-**** inside every city.
3- Finally need to access the inner attributes for every CN and get the value of it.

The code I used in **views.py** is :

```py
def index(request):
    cities_list = []
    gateways_list = []
    con = ldap.initialize('ldap://The_URI_For_IDAP/(|(OU=Brasil)(OU=Company)(OU=Organization))')
    some_dn = 'dc=*****,dc=com'
    query = "ou=*"
    result = con.search_s(some_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, query)
    for item in result:
        cities_list.append(city_name)
        print(item)
    context = {
        'cities_list': cities_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

in the `cities_list` i get a list of every Parent city ou after `ou=Brasil` but i can't get to the inner `Ou` and also can't reach the `CN` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grab every entry under `ou=Organization >> ou=Company >> ou=Brasil`, you need to set the base dn accordingly and use `objectclass=*` as filter :

```
con = ldap.initialize('ldap://domain.com')
base_dn = 'ou=Brasil,ou=Company,ou=Organization,dc=domain,dc=com'
filter = "(objectClass=*)"
result = con.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter)
```